# Gnome session broken on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gdm, 17.10, wayland, gnome-session

My dell inspiron 660s with intel graphics ran Ubuntu 16.04.3 for a year with no issues, and I decided to give 17.10 a try.

After installing 17.10, ubuntu restricted extras, lowlatency kernel, and applying all updates and rebooting, GDM fails to start.

Here are some relevant log entries:

```
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia gnome-session[2984]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 256
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia gnome-session-c[3030]: eglGetDisplay() failed
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia gnome-session[2984]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 256
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia gnome-session[2984]: gnome-session-binary[2984]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia gnome-session[2984]: gnome-session-binary[2984]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia gnome-session-binary[2984]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia gnome-session-binary[2984]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia org.a11y.atspi.Registry[3002]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Oct 21 14:27:24 olympia org.a11y.atspi.Registry[3002]:       after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had, what seemed to be, the same problem. In my case the headers didn't get installed during the upgrade and thus the video driver never got built.

Here's what I did:

1. installed `linux-headers-lowlatency`
2. ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-384`
3. make sure wayland was enabled in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` (I had changed it before)

I may have uninstalled nouveau (`xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` package) but I think it was getting the driver module built/installed and re-enabling wayland (after I disabled it trying to get things working) that did the trick for me.

FYI, for me everything feels sluggish, and it doesn't take refresh-rate changes.. but that's a problem for another day.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this problem with headers and nvidia driver happen on my other desktop which has an nvidia card. But the machine in question above is just straight onboard intel video, so you'd think nothing could go wrong....

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed the "intel graphics" part of your post, my bad. ><

Comment: The problems with 17.10 were not resolved. I decided to go ahead and install the daily build of 18.04, which, as it turns out, works, even at this early stage. I won't pursue the 17.10 issues any longer